# MP Chart using socket in flutter

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, mpandroidchart

I need to update MP chart using socket in flutter. I have attached screenshot and short description is: in X-axis the data is in order of 0,1,2,3....Now, instead of this I want to update X-axis like shown in image (in time format hh:mm: a). how can I achieve this in line chart controller.

[image]